# Flexbox child items use full space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm building a site with flexbox, I have a problem that I can't fix.

```css
.min-h-screen {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  flex:1;
  background: red;
}

.child-one {
  background: green;
  display:flex;
}

.child-two {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-h-screen">
  <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-one">
          <p>
           child 1
          </p>
      </div>

       <div class="child-two">
           <p>
           child 2
           </p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the `child 1` and `child 2` use the full space, right now they don't. How could I fix this. Already tried a lot. `Height 100 %` does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use nested flex containers.

```css
.min-h-screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  display: flex; /* new */
  flex-direction: column; /* new */
}

.child-one {
  flex: 1; /* new */
  background: green;
  display: flex;
}

.child-two {
  flex: 1; /* new */
  background: yellow;
}
 
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="min-h-screen">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-one">
      <p>
        child 1
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="child-two">
      <p>
        child 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: there is a reason to use nested flex containers having a surplus of html?

Comment: The reason to add flex containers is that they come with the default setting of `align-items: stretch`, which gives the flex children full height automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent { 
     min-height: 100vh;
     display:flex;
     background: red;
     flex-direction: column; 
 }

.child-one {
     background: green; 
     flex: 1 0 50%; 
}

.child-two { 
     background: yellow; 
     flex: 1 0 50%; 
 }
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
      <div class="child-one">
          <p>
           child 1
          </p>
      </div>

       <div class="child-two">
           <p>
           child 2
           </p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just gotta flex the parent of the those two elements too.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.min-h-screen {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.parent {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}

.child-one {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}

.child-two {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="min-h-screen">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child-one">
      <p>
        child 1
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="child-two">
      <p>
        child 2
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```